# SQL How do I insert into select the following data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a FK into my playlistvideos table from playlist table.
The following code should look sometime like this

```
INSERT INTO playlistvideos(videoID, playlistFK, videoTitle, videoLink, thumbnail) VALUES (2,playlistID,'JWD','JWD.mp4,'JWD.jpg')
SELECT playlist.playlistID
FROM playlist
WHERE playlist.userFK = 'Armistice' AND playlist.icon = 'Heart'
```

playlist:

```
playlistID | name      | userfk | icon
1          | Favourite | Armistice | Heart
```

videos:

```
videoID | videoTitle| videoLink | Thumbnail
2       | JWD       | JWD.mp4   | JWD.jpg
```

The Following output should be
playlistvideos:

```
videoID | playlistFK| videoTitle | videoLink | Thumbnail
2       | 1         | JWD        | JWD.mp4   | JWD.jpg
```

Comment: Are you looking to insert `SELECT playlist.playlistID...` data into column `playlistFK`?

Comment: There exists `INSERT .. SELECT` and `INSERT .. VALUES`. But `INSERT .. VALUES .. SELECT` - not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INSERT .. SELECT`.

```sql
INSERT INTO playlistvideos (videoID, playlistFK, videoTitle, videoLink, thumbnail) 
SELECT 2, playlistID, 'JWD', 'JWD.mp4', 'JWD.jpg'
FROM playlist
WHERE userFK = 'Armistice' 
  AND icon = 'Heart'
```

SELECT may select both columns values and literal values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to insert the value of `SELECT playlist.playlistID...` into your `playlistFK` column

```
INSERT INTO playlistvideos(videoID, playlistFK, videoTitle, videoLink, thumbnail) VALUES (2,
(SELECT playlist.playlistID
FROM playlist
WHERE playlist.userFK = 'Armistice' AND playlist.icon = 'Heart'
),'JWD','JWD.mp4,'JWD.jpg')
```

Comment: The subquery may return more than one row - in this case the query will fail. Also the subquery may return none rows, and NULL will be inserted for `playlistFK` - I doubt that OP needs in this.

Comment: It did no work. Thanks for helping tho